# Bash logger output

Tags: linux, bash, logging

I'm writing bash logger, that logs every single line of the script.

I have this:

```
exec > >(tee $LOG) 2>&1

trap "echo 'ERROR: An error occurred during execution, check log $LOGFILE for details.' >&3" ERR
trap '{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null; echo -n "$(date '+[%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S]') "; set -x' DEBUG
```

But the problem is, that the log file is nice (timestamps, commands, outputs). But I would prefer to not have timestamps and commands in terminal.

Is there a way to print only outputs into terminal, and everything into a file?
I'm not sure if this is possible with exec command or I need different approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect your tracing to a different stream by setting `BASH_XTRACEFD`, and you can prefix the date by setting `PS4`.  So create a stream that writes directly to the log file, and use that for your command tracing.  And `tee` your outputs using the `--append` option, to the same file.

```
truncate -s 0 "$LOG"
exec 3>>"$LOG"
exec &> >(tee -a "$LOG")

PS4='+\D{[%Y-%m-%d][%H:%M:%S]} '
BASH_XTRACEFD=3

trap 'echo "ERROR: An error occurred during execution, check log $LOG for details." >&2' ERR

set -x
```

Comment: Is there any way to print output of each command after that command in output file? For now output log file looks like list of commands executed THEN list of outputs of these commands.

Comment: You could try making the `tee` unbuffered, using `stdbuf` command.